# How to display rss from external site into a view and sort them?

Tags: views, 7, feeds

I want to import RSS from an external website and then display them in a view content pane. I also have to sort them by date. The External RSS contains Title, Body and Date but the Date is hidden by default in RSS, I guess. I checked the Aggregator and feeds module but I don't think it serves the purpose because i also have to link the title to the Nodes on the External site.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If feeds are read by drupal core aggregator module then you can do this with the help of views module itself.

Rough Example: Settings as per the screenshots

1. Create new view[image]
2. Add fields to your view.

[image]

[image]

This will show feeds in view and you can easily do whatever you want to do with it.
Hopes this will help.

Comment: Thank you @Gaurav for your useful comment. If you look at my question, it says it should import the pubDate from RSS but by default the Aggregator doesn't bring the pubDate from RSS, how can I do that? I have already accepted your reply as Answer but I also need that one.

Comment: In second screenshot there is field named: Aggregator: Timestamp- The date the original feed item was posted. (With some feeds, this will be the date it was imported.)

Comment: Yes, I have already added it, but it shows the time when the rss was imported into the local system and not the time when it was posted on the remote server :(.

Comment: @rashidkhan I got what you said, but in my case where I tested the above is in live environment and shows the exact post date of respective blog/post.